# rsync - same size, content, owner, group, permissions, time - yet it wants to copy

Tags: macos, backup, rsync, fat32, apfs

rsync - same size, content, owner, group, permissions, time - yet it wants to copy

Using macOS Mojave. Using the default filesystem in the source dir (`apfs` per `df`?), FAT32 in the dest dir (`msdos` per `df`).

Run out of ideas.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `--modify-window=1`. From the `rsync` man page:

```
--modify-window
          When  comparing  two  timestamps, rsync treats the timestamps as
          being equal if they differ by no  more  than  the  modify-window
          value.   This  is  normally  0 (for an exact match), but you may
          find it useful to set this to a larger value in some situations.
          In  particular,  when  transferring to or from an MS Windows FAT
          filesystem (which represents times with a 2-second  resolution),
          --modify-window=1 is useful (allowing times to differ by up to 1
          second).
```

Comment: You saved the day.